# How to use complex numbers in geometry

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

Let $H$ be the orthocenter of an acute-angled triangle $ABC$. The circle $\Gamma_{A}$ centered at the midpoint of $BC$ and passing through $H$ intersects the sideline $BC$ at points  $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$. Similarly, define the points $B_{1}$, $B_{2}$, $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$.
Prove that six points $A_{1}$ , $A_{2}$, $B_{1}$, $B_{2}$,  $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ are concyclic.

This is problem from IMO 2008. Can someone explain me how to solve this problem with using complex numbers?I am trying,but have problem with finding intersection of circle and line $BC$.

Comment: I find the condition to use complex numbers quite tricky, with a lot of messy calculations... Wouldn't a geometrical proof meet the requirements?

Comment: Of course,but i want to know how to solve some problems with complex numbers...